# Is it possible to make two cards one below the other?

Tags: flutter, dart, containers, flutter-container, flutter-card

I have a question: I need **two cards one below the other**. I´ve tried it with the code bellow, but the second "child" from the container is red underliend and I as a beginner don't know why. And yes I know, child is only one and children are more than one, but I don´t know how it should work with children. I would be happy if someone could help me with this (probably easy to solve) problem. Thanks in advance!

```
Container(
  child: Card(
    child: InkWell(
      splashColor: Colors.blue.withAlpha(30),
      onTap: () {
        print Text("Got it");
      },
      child: Container(
        child: Text("title", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
        //width: 300,
        height: 100,
        color: Colors.blue,
      ),
    ),
  ),
  child: Card(
    child: InkWell(
      splashColor: Colors.blue.withAlpha(30),
      onTap: () {
        print Text("Got it");
      },
      child: Container(
        child: Text("title", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
        //width: 300,
        height: 100,
        color: Colors.blue,
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Comment: Instead of Container, use `Column` widget, you can add multiple children to a column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a `Column` widget to show multiple widgets one below the other, like this:

```
Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    Card(
      child: InkWell(
        splashColor: Colors.blue.withAlpha(30),
        onTap: () {
          print("Got it");
        },
        child: Container(
          child: Text("title", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
          //width: 300,
          height: 100,
          color: Colors.blue,
        ),
      ),
    ),
    Card(
      child: InkWell(
        splashColor: Colors.blue.withAlpha(30),
        onTap: () {
          print("Got it");
        },
        child: Container(
          child: Text("title", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
          //width: 300,
          height: 100,
          color: Colors.blue,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ]
),
```